# How run stoplight prism mock from docker image

Tags: docker, api, mocking

I am trying to run the prism mock server from docker stoplight/prism image, but I didn't find simple documentation to run from volume (not from HTTP external link).

This is my approach: attach the volume with my local API definitions at the local `~/apis` directory

```
@ ~/apis () $ ls
openapi.yml
```

And run in this way

```
 $ docker run --rm -v ~/apis:/tmp -t stoplight/prism mock -p 4010 --host 0.0.0.0 /tmp/openapi.yaml 
 [10:16:46 AM] › [CLI] …  awaiting  Starting Prism…
 [10:16:47 AM] › [CLI] ✖  fatal     Error opening file "/tmp/openapi.yaml" 
 ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/openapi.yaml'
```

**Edited**

After Neo Anderson put me on the right way, I am able to run the mock server in this way :

```
docker run --rm -v ~/apis:/root/apis -p 9003:4010 -t stoplight/prism mock -h 0.0.0.0 /root/apis/openapi.yml
```

Watch run docker logs and try the URLs, like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:9003/myapi/path...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `*.yml` in the volume and `.yaml` in the docker run command.
You may fix it on either side.
Everything else looks good.

Comment: how silly can i get .... thanks Neo!!!  It works now.

Comment: @danipenaperez, It happens :). Our brains can do amazing things: It deosn't mttaer in waht oredr the ltteers in a wrod are, the olny iprmoetnt tihng is taht the frist and lsat ltteer be at the rghit pclae. The rset can be a toatl mses and you can sitll raed it wouthit porbelm. Tihs is bcuseae the huamn mnid deos not raed ervey lteter by istlef, but the wrod as a wlohe.